# Jmeter incrementing the path value

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a scenario of uploading a product image . I recorded the scenario using proxy server
but the image is not uploaded. I tried by moving the images to the bin folder and then did the same still the image is not uploaded. Can anyone help me to rectify this issue.
My code is :

```
                         Send parameter with request
 Name         Value
 _method      POST

                         Send files with request

file path                      Parameter name                       MIME type
C:/loc/jmeter/bin/img.jpg      data[Product][product_image]         image/jpeg
```

Actually the problem is with the HTTP Requests Path because when i add an image using proxy server

```
HTTP Requests
Server Name: Server.com
path:/products/image/1147
```

Using the same path i was not able to upload images but when i change the
    " path:/products/image/1148 "
Was able to upload image but every time i cant change this. 
Is there any way to automate it.
Please help me..

Comment: Please post your comments

Comment: Thanks  Found the Solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have following configuration:

1. `POST` method is selected from drop-down.
   2.`Use multipart/form-data for POST` box checked
2. `Parameter name` exactly matches relevant input of type "file" at upload page
3. Any other correlation and session attributes are fine, i.e. session ID, cookies, etc.

Also it worth checking jmeter.log and log of your web/application server or proxy for any errors.

See [Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks But the every time when i add a image. Image added in the application its value incremented. EX: i add a product image in the http Request  path: /products/image/1147 for the next time when i add the image i have to change the path: /products/image/1148

Comment: I guess that you can use either __counter() function https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter or should be able to extract the value via i.e. Regular Expressions Extractor http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T used Regular Expression Extractor getting the output.